# Cytoscape.js: Overlapping edge labels in multigraph

Tags: cytoscape.js

There are several posts about edge or edge label overlaps in Cytoscape.js but the answers given there, like smaller labels and more spaced out nodes, don't help for a multigraph, i.e. a graph where two nodes can have multiple edges between them.

Is there a way to spread out edge labels even if they all belong to edges between the same two nodes? The edge pairs occur both in the same direction and in the reverse one.

As my graph is verly large, I would prefer a solution with haystack edges as the performance is already low.

Comment: I don't think you will get an answer to this question... It has been asked before and answered before (by the develeoper of cytoscape.js himself) and (if there wasn't a really sick update for this), the answer now would be the same as back then?

Comment: Also, haystack edges are straight lines, you can't "space them out" like bezier edges (which are probably way more suitable for you)

Comment: @Stephan T.: I don't want to space out the edges but the labels.

Comment: What exactly does that mean? I don't quite understand the spacing out part. How do you plan on moving the edges, you can position them via text alignment, but that has to be about it?

Comment: @Stephan T. : The edge labels are all in the horizontal center of a non rotated edge. I want them to to be offset along the edge, like varying x margins but rotated with the edge.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can rotate the text with "text-rotation": "autorotate" in the labels css. You can also define the "text-margin-x/y" for each node itself, but how do you plan on defining the position for each and every label? Lets assume, you did that perfectly: you would still need to do a reposition event after moving just one node, because the offsets will be off by then:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "border-width": "10px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "$node > node",
      css: {
        "padding-top": "10px",
        "padding-left": "10px",
        "padding-bottom": "10px",
        "padding-right": "10px",
        "text-valign": "top",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "background-color": "#bbb"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge[label]",
      css: {
        "label": "data(label)",
        "text-rotation": "autorotate",
        "text-margin-x": "data(xalign)",
        "text-margin-y": "data(yalign)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ":selected",
      css: {
        "background-color": "black",
        "line-color": "black",
        "target-arrow-color": "black",
        "source-arrow-color": "black"
      }
    }
  ],
  layout: {
    name: "circle"
  }
}));

var info = [{
    name: "Peter",
    next_op_name: "Claire"
  },
  {
    name: "Claire",
    next_op_name: "Mike"
  },
  {
    name: "Mike",
    next_op_name: "Rosa"
  },
  {
    name: "Rosa",
    next_op_name: "Peter"
  }
];

cy.ready(function() {
  var array = [];
  // iterate over info once
  for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    array.push({
      group: "nodes",
      data: {
        id: info[i].name, // id is name!!!
        label: info[i].name
      }
    });
    array.push({
      group: "edges",
      data: {
        id: "e" + i,
        source: info[i].name,
        target: info[i].next_op_name,
        label: "e" + i,
        xalign: (i == 0 || i == 1 ? '15px' : '-15px'),
        yalign: (i == 0 || i == 3 ? '15px' : '-15px')
      }
    });
  }
  cy.add(array);
  cy.layout({
    name: "circle"
  }).run();
});
cy.on("mouseover", "node", function(event) {
  var node = event.target;
  node.qtip({
      content: "hello",
      show: {
        event: event.type,
        ready: true
      },
      hide: {
        event: "mouseout unfocus"
      }
    },
    event
  );
});

cy.on("tapdrag", "node", function(event) {
  // update all relevant labels
  var labels = event.target.connectedEdges();
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    // render with the right positions?
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <!-- qtip imports -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/2.7.0/cytoscape-qtip.js"></script>

  <!-- dagre imports -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem breaks down to this: the task seems simple, but keeping track of the positions of all nodes and the edges aaaaand your rendered labels is a sisyphean task.